# User's Comments: returning 500 error?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

It looks like when I try to get the comments of a user that has "a huge number" of comments, I get a 500 error.

Jon Skeet's comments, 500 error: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/22656/comments

Whereas a smaller query works just fine:

rascher's comments: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/3788/comments

I even get this error when I set a small page size. What is the threshold for "this is too many comments for the API to deliver?" Could we obtain some metrics - like the number of comments or paging thresholds - before the request is rejected outright?

Comment: This is definitely a bug.

Comment: haha, it turns out that using Jon Skeet's profile is an *excellent* way to bench-test your app!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jon's comment history finally grew large enough to overflow some limits in that query.  Its been fixed.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much for looking into this!

Comment: 'Finally'...? Jon Skeet outgrew his comment history on StackOverflow before he joined StackOverflow.